# json format of highchart speedometer

Tags: json, getjson

What is the `JSON` format that a high-charts speedometer accepts? Please help me on this as I am very new to high-charts.

Comment: Review their documentation: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/46-gauges-ranges-and-polar-charts-in-beta , the `Gauge examples` will give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: **@fmendez Thank you. But can you be more specific about the format? Like, it is an array of arrays for a pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

A speedometer only requires one value for it's dataseries. e.g. data: [80] sets the speed to 80.

Here is a basic example which shows a speed of 80:

```
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'gauge',
    },     
    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        }  
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]  
},
```

Here is an example of it, with a function updating it using point.update: http://jsfiddle.net/JYjP7/

Comment: ok. but I want add data dynamically to the chart. How can that be done?

Comment: You can't really add data, as a speedometer only shows one point. However, you can update it using chart.series[0].setData([55]);

Comment: I have the following output in JSON format from a servlet program.   {"a":"20","b":"22"}                                                  How can I display it on the speedometer?First it should display 20 and then 22. Can you help me on this?

Comment: First call chart.series[0].points[0].update(data.a), and then after a few seconds, call chart.series[0].points[0].update(data.b).